# Dart: Target of URI does not exist

Tags: import, compiler-errors, dart, project-structure

My Dart app project structure:

```
myapp/
    pubspec.yaml
    pubspec.lock
    asset/
        ...assets
    build/
    packages/
    web/
        lookups/
            AjaxLookups.dart
        requests/
            RESTClient.dart
            AjaxRESTClient.dart
```

The **AjaxLookups** file:

```
library myapp;

abstract class AjaxLookups {
    static final String BASE_URL = "/myapp";
    static final String DO_S0METHING_SERVICE_URL = BASE_URL + "/doSomething";
}
```

The **RESTClient** file:

```
library myapp;

typedef void Callback(String json);

abstract class RESTClient {
    void get(String url, Callback onFail, Callback onSuccess);

    void post(String url, String dataJSON, Callback onFail, Callback onSuccess);
}
```

The **AjaxRESTClient** file:

```
library myapp;

import "RESTClient.dart";
import "../lookups/AjaxLookups.dart";
import "dart:html";
import "dart:convert" show JSON;

class AjaxRESTClient implements RESTClient, AjaxLookups {
    // ...
}
```

Above, the import statement for `AjaxLookups` is causing a compiler error:

> Target of URI does not exist: '../request/AjaxLookups.dart'

Why am I getting this? Why can't Dart find `../request/AjaxLookups.dart`? What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file AjaxLookups.dart is in the lookups folder, so your import should be:

```
import "../lookups/AjaxLookups.dart";
```

Comment: Sorry @ringstaff - that was a cut-n-paste error - my import statement *did* contain "lookups" in it instead of "request" - thanks thought!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was declaring a new `myapp` library inside each source file. Instead I added a main/driver Dart file, declared a library in it called `myapp`, and then changed all the other source files to be `part of myapp;`.